# How to profile Craft CMS

Tags: database

I would like to turn on a profiler in Craft CMS so I can see what DB queries are being run and how long they take.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup! Just turn on [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) in your [general config](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings):

```php
return array(
    'devMode' => true,
);
```

And then just open up a console (Firebug, Chrome, etc) and look in the profiling summary report.